# how to toggle in between 2 classes in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, toggleclass

i have an issue doing `toggleClass` it doesn't seem to work properly. the image should change in between `show` and `hide`. It does change in to `hide`, but no back

here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/wNXRS/) and some code:

```
<div class="top_menu_hidden" style="display: none; ">testing</div>
<div class="show_menu"></div>

$('.show_menu').on('click', function(){
        $('.top_menu_hidden').stop().slideToggle('normal', function(){
            $(".show_menu").toggleClass("hide_menu show_menu");
        });
});​

.show_menu{
    background: url("http://placehold.it/150&text=show") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
.hide_menu{
    background: url("http://placehold.it/150&text=hide") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".show_menu, .hide_menu").toggleClass("hide_menu show_menu");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wNXRS/2/)**

**Full code**

```
$('.show_menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.top_menu_hidden').stop().slideToggle('normal', function() {
        $(".show_menu, .hide_menu").toggleClass("hide_menu show_menu");
    });
});
```

Comment: Will you stop copy answers??? If you think yours is better, write it, if don't don't. Don't write your's than copy the rest from the other answers! It's the third time I'm telling you that.

Comment: @gdoron Am I missing something? I don't see a smiliarity between this post and yours.

Answer (score 4):

There is a toggle function that does it for you out of the box:

```
$(".show_menu").toggle();
```

`toggle` docs:

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

Comment: Good point. This, of course, only applies if the classes dictate visibility ONLY.

Comment: @Dutchie432. Of course thecodeparadox copied it... He does it all the time!

Comment: @Dutchie432. You have more than 10K so you can [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11048059/601179). This is only one example.